# use multithreading to copy and then use database

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlcipher

there is some facts:
1. i have a Database that with sqlcipher Encryption.
2. my database is 30 MB (it's heavy)
3. i must copy database from assets to device at first time use of application.

But my problem:
i don't use multi thread for this Operations but this cause errors on some devices.
so how i can manage this in better way:
first copy database to device in a thread and **then** start work with database.
i use:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // COPY OPERATION
    }
});
thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
thread.start();
```

but it seems that reading database starts before ending copy and causes errors.

Comment: use uithread  because simple thread doent wait. it work own self and main thread give authority to work separate.

Comment: Thanks. but what i do with unwanted memory errors

Comment: put your logs to understand error

Comment: unfortunately the device that makes errors is not available by me. someone email me about error and i tested application on many devices and simulators but not error happens. so i just know that must Optimize app to mange memory and processing :(

Comment: by the way i can upload my codes. Although they are complicated and contains many classes

Comment: here is my codes:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlYa8g7Qe0dOU9oTWU3T29XR2s/view?usp=sharing